# JQuery Tablesorter - Currency column not sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery table sorter with success except for my currency column which is in euros.

This is my ASC result (It's only reading the first number?):

€102
€105
€110
€120
€29
€35
€40

How do I make it so that 29 is first and not 102????

Comment: i've come across this problem as well, and limited time forced me to drop the eurosign. In my case I fixed the missing sign by backgrounding it in an image with CSS. Pretty hacky, but since you state it's only for internal use, this could be used as a quickfix.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I ran into the same trouble, and thought I'd post my solution in case anyone else has the same problem.

I've got columns with various symbols following the decimal numbers, such as u (units), g (grams) and €.

What WTK posted above is correct, however the column count he's posting is NOT correct. He wrote '2' for column 2, but the count starts at 0, so if you want to sort on column 2, you need to write 1.

As I use US-style decimals, I also had to force this in the code.
Here's what worked for me:

```
        $('#mainTable').tablesorter({
            usNumberFormat: true,
            headers: {
                // column number 6, with contents such as: 1.04 g
                5: {
                    sorter: "currency"
                },
                // column number 7, with contents such as: 1.04 u
                6: {
                    sorter: "currency"
                },
                // column number 9, with contents such as: 1.04 €
                8: {
                    sorter: "currency"
                },
                // column number 10, with contents such as: 1.04 €
                9: {
                    sorter: "currency"
                },
                // column number 11, with contents such as: 1.04 €
                10: {
                    sorter: "currency"
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work well if you replace the euro sign with a dollar sign?

If so, than most probably your euro sign is provided as html entity instead of regular utf character and therefor tablesorter plugin doesn't know that it has to treat that column values as a currency. Hence the wrong sorting.

If, on the other hand, you have a proper euro sign in front of your currency values then you can try forcing tablesorter to treat given column as a currency. Like this:

```
// Create a tablesorter interface and set a column parser for the second column.
$('#example-table').tablesorter({ headers: { 2: {sorter:"currency"} } });
```

Update: check the source code for you tablesorter plugin, take a closer look at this lines:

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "currency",
    is: function (s) {
        return /^[ÂŁ$âŹ?.]/.test(s);
    }, format: function (s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(new RegExp(/[ÂŁ$âŹ]/g), ""));
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

At line 4 and line 6 you can see a regex - the column is treated as currency if it passes the test at line 4. Maybe (as here in the example above), encoding of the characters in regexp is messed up. To make sure they're ok, replace the  them with your euro character.

Comment: Hmmm well I've tried putting € infront and & euro; - and tried both afterwards and it always breaks it!

Neither symbol works though ($ does but obviously no good to me!) - So I guess I have to stick the Euro symbol in the TH which is a shame! That headers thing didn't change anything, even though I change 2 to 9 as it's the 9th column

Comment: I can't unfortunately as it's internal. But clearly the Euro symbol seems to mess up the data sorting, the $ is fine so I'll just have to display my data without the currency symbol after each value!

Comment: I've updated my answer. To put it simple - check the encoding of characters that symbolize currency in your tablesorter plugin source.